# Jquery attr function does not work in IE7

Tags: jquery, attr

I am using jQuery 1.3.2, It seems the attr function does work in IE8 and FF 3 but not in IE7.

The problematic code:

```
.attr("disabled",true)
```

or

```
 .attr("disabled","disabled")
```

Is there an alternative way to disable an element? (a specific option in a SELECT element)

Thank you.

Comment: You should post complete line with selector as well and possibly the html too.

Comment: is your html validated?... it might be causing that problem...

Comment: The `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` function works more than nicely on all major browsers. It is some other part of your code that doesn't work but cannot say as you didn't paste it.

Answer (score 2):

IE 7 does not support `disabled` in select options. It's not a jQuery issue.

There's detailed info in [this blog post](http://www.lattimore.id.au/2005/06/18/disable-options-in-a-select-dropdown-element/).

There are Javascript based workarounds like [this one](http://elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com/2007/05/activating-option-disabled-in-ie.html) that add the functionality (however, even they are not able to give the select the greyed-out look.)